# systemrequarments for developing with the oculus rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion, oculus, oculus-runtime

I want do develop in Unity a little game with the Leap Motion and Oculus rift. 
Now i have a Surface Pro 3 (i7 version) and a macbook Air (13, 2015).
Is that suffizient? What kind of system-requirements i need?

Thank you for help.

Comment: The requirements for *use* are on their homepage. For development you might need more. (I doubt that your Surface comes close, and Macs are unsupported)

Comment: https://www.oculus.com/en-us/oculus-ready-pcs/ https://support.leapmotion.com/entries/39315178-What-are-the-system-requirements- System requirements are heaviest for the Rift, and you do not match them. Especially where it concerns the recommended GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oculus SDK doesn't support OSX after version 0.5, and the Leap Motion Orion software is currently Windows-only. It is possible to build a (very outdated, simple) game on your platform using the Oculus 0.5 SDK and the older Leap Motion Core Assets, but unless this is a personal experiment, you don't have much chance of taking it further without upgrading to an Oculus-ready PC running Windows.